# Custom view ChipTabView is missing constructor used by tools: (Context) or (Context,AttributeSet) or (Context,AttributeSet,int). Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey i tried to pass parameter in custom view class. It giving warning **Custom view ChipTabView is missing constructor used by tools: (Context) or (Context,AttributeSet) or (Context,AttributeSet,int)**. I don't want to use **suppressLint** How to remove this warning can some one help me. I tried to this [Custom view is missing constructor used by tools for adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063090/custom-view-is-missing-constructor-used-by-tools-for-adapter)
 I don't want to change settings for android studio. I need proper solution how to achieve this in clean manner. Thanks in advance

[image]

```
class ChipTabView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    private val number: Int,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own unique secondary constructor like this

```
class ChipTabView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var number: Int = 0         

    constructor(number: Int, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttribute: Int = 0) : this(context, attrs, defStyleAttribute) {
        this.number = number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `private val number: Int` to make the constructor arguments conform to layout inflater requirements.

You can use a setter function to pass in values to your custom view.